# Are self-closing tags, e.g. <tag />, legal in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

In the Vue documentation, I have seen opening and closing tags, but I've seen in other places where authors write components as self closing tags, like `<some-component />`

Is the practice of self-closing tags legal in Vue?

Comment: [Self-closing components | Vue Style Guide](https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Self-closing-components-strongly-recommended)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the Vue style guide:

> Components with no content should be self-closing in single-file
> components, string templates, and JSX - but never in DOM templates.

It's legal and strongly recommended by the Vue style guide:
[Vue Style Guide #self-closing components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Self-closing-components-strongly-recommended)

Answer (score 5):

Both the questions are answered above. But, I would like to point out what exactly is meant by no content in self closing tags.

1. When we use `<div><p>Something</p></div>`, `<p>` tag here is the content and hence, we cannot use div as a self closing tag.
2. Similarly in case of Vue JS components, you can also include content inside the component tags. e.g., `<MyComponent><p>Something Else</p></MyComponent>`.
   Then, in the component definition of `<MyComponent>`, you have to includes  to render the content passed wherever `<MyComponent>` is used.
3. If you intend to not have any content to be passed from the `<MyComponent>`. i.e. If you do not have the `<slot>` tag in the definition of your component, then your  `<MyComponent>` can be a self closing tag.